# How to give access to Accounting Settings for an user in Odoo14?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I want to give access of **Accounting Settings** to an user. The settings app was not accessible at first. So, I created a group for the user, gave menu, view and model access rights. Now The user can see the settings option in the accounting module also in the app list, but still can not access. I can not add the user in the **Administrator / Settings** group because I don't want the user to give the full permission of Settings. How can I give the user proper access rights. The warning is not enough to understand what permission I am missing. I am attaching some images of access rights.

**1. User is added in the group.**
[image]
**2. Menu access rights**
[image]
**3. View access rights**
[image]
**4. Model access rights.**
[image]

Comment: what's the warning you're getting ?

Comment: there is no warnings. Mainly, I don't want the group users to access other settings (example: purchase settings, sales settings). I just want the group users to show the accounting settings portion.